# How can I make an Array with Dictionaris in SwiftUI, and then call them?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swiftui

so simple / hard question here.. So I want to have a list of dictionaries titles in an array, then use the array to call a random dictionary

in the textfield I want dic1 "A" ("first")

how can I get this?

```
 let dic1 = [
"A" : "first",
"B" : "second"]
 let dic2 = [
"A" : "one",
"B" : "two"
]

var dicArray = ["dic1", "dic2"]

text("\(dicArray[0])")
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes: `let dicArray = [dic1, dic2]`

Comment: thank you, but how do I then get the value "A"? I can "print(dicArray[0])" and get ["B": "second", "A": "first"], but I only want "first"

Comment: `dicArray[0]["A"]` (`A` is the **key**, the value is `first`). With a custom struct it would be still more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks! for the help! now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides removing the quotes when you instantiate dicArray, you need to do more work in `Text`. The way you instantiated `dicArray`, you made it an `[String]`, not an `[[String:String]]`. The full view would be:

```
struct DictView: View {
    let dic1 = [
        "A" : "first",
        "B" : "second"]
    let dic2 = [
        "A" : "one",
        "B" : "two"
    ]
    
    var dicArray: [[String:String]]
    init() {
        dicArray = [dic1, dic2]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(dicArray[0]["A"] ?? "")")
    }
}
```

Remember, because it is a dictionary, there is no guarantee that there is a key:value for "A" so you have to deal with the optional as well.

Comment: Thanks! looks like its working in playground now, will try to add this to my app :D

Comment: As @vadian implied, this really isn't the recommended way to do this. You should have the dictionary as a separate type, and then have all of the variables be of the same type. It makes it cleaner. And remember, a `Dict` is already a collection. Essentially, you are making a collection of a collection.

Comment: yes your way worked perfectly!